# Algorithm - Calculating notch values on a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, range

Given these inputs: start, end, number of notches

```
start = a number;
end = a larger number;
numberOfNotches = a number; // includes start and end values
```

How would I calculate the intermediate values on a range for display?

Ex:

```
start = 100;
end = 200;
numberOfNotches = 6; // includes start and end values
```

Output:

```
100 ----- 120 ----- 140 ----- 160 ----- 180 ----- 200
```

Here is what I have so far in JavaScript

```
function getNotchValues(from, to, numberOfNotches){
    var step = Math.floor( ( (to - from) / (numberOfNotches-2) ));

    from = Math.floor(from/step)*step;
    to = Math.ceil(to/step)*step;
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=from; i<=to; i=i+step){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here's the logic I have so far, but it's not working out for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w8vwG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an [off-by-one/fencepost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) problem. Appears to work fine with one small change:

```
(numberOfNotches-1)
```

In this line:

```
var step = Math.floor( ( (to - from) / (numberOfNotches-1) ));
```

Edit:

I think this is a complete solution, handling the issue in my comment below:

http://jsfiddle.net/RKx87/

```
function getNotchValues(from, to, numberOfNotches) {
    var step = Math.floor(((to - from) / (numberOfNotches - 1)));

    var arr = [];
    for (var i = from; i <= to; i = i + step) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    arr[arr.length - 1] = to
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Hm, looks like it works now as long as `to - from` is evenly divisible by `numberOfNotches - 1`. You can get it closer by not rounding the step, but rounding later. That may make you end up off by one on the last element though.

Comment: The issue is the last one goes over the range due to the step being calculated

Comment: See my update. I rounded later, and adjusted the last item in the array to be equal to the `to` value.

Comment: The value is still off http://jsfiddle.net/v8mJz/1/ - your fiddle with different values